# Counting all occurrences on database table based on timestamp and grouping them by days

Tags: mysql

I have a table named stats with the following columns:
id, product, timestamp
It stores all the products sold with the timestamp. 
I would like to know how many of each product have been sold on each day.
I'm trying some query but still not found the right way. 
Thanks.

I tried:

```
SELECT timestamp, count(nome_prodotto) AS total 
FROM statistiche 
GROUP BY timestamp
```

Comment: Show some of the queries you tried. You just need `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)`

Comment: SELECT timestamp, count(nome_prodotto) AS total
FROM statistiche 
GROUP BY timestamp

It works but I don't have the product_name in query response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DATE()` to combine all the timestamps on the same date into a single group.

And if you want separate counts for each product, that needs to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, nome_produtto, COUNT(*) as total
FROM statistiche
GROUP BY date, nome_produtto
```

Comment: Mmmm no, this is not what I need. For example I would need a result like this:
05/17/19 - ITEM1 - 2 sold
05/17/19 - ITEM2 - 1 sold
05/18/19 - ITEM1 - 3 sold
05/19/19 - ITEM3 - 1 sold

I think that I solved it with this query
SELECT nome_prodotto, timestamp, count(nome_prodotto) FROM statistiche GROUP BY timestamp
but I have to change sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: You need `nome_produtto` in the `GROUP BY`, not in `COUNT()`.